# Find and copy/paste last columns

Tags: vba, excel, range, paste

I have a problem inserting new columns and pasting the values of the last columns in these new columns.

The code I got so far is this

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LC As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TOT")
LC = ws.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ws.Columns(LC - 2).Insert
ws.Columns(LC - 2).Insert
ws.Columns(LC - 2).Insert
ws.Columns(LC + 1 & ":" & LC + 3).Copy
ws.Range(LC + 1 & "1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

I want to insert three new colums in front of the last three existing columns and paste the values of the last three existing columns in the three new columns. There are no merged cells in these areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I was not aware of this

> Both the Copy and the PasteSpecial methods must be used on a Range >reference/object. You are trying to use Copy on a Columns reference

I have rearranged my code as follows and this works out

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LC As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TOT")
LC = ws.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ws.Columns(LC - 2).Insert
ws.Columns(LC - 2).Insert
ws.Columns(LC - 2).Insert
ws.Range(Columns(LC + 1), Columns(LC + 3)).Copy
ws.Range(Columns(LC - 2), Columns(LC)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ws.Range(Columns(LC - 2), Columns(LC)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: Since the 3 columns being inserted are exactly same as last 3 already existing.
 _I want to insert three new colums in front of the last three existing columns and paste the values of the last three existing columns in the three new columns_
Unless there is a defined _“Name”_ in the data. It is any?
Why not copying the last 3 columns after the last column, instead of inserting new columns?

Comment: You're right. I have no idea why I did not think of that earlier

Answer (score 0):

Both the `Copy` and the `PasteSpecial` methods must be used on a `Range` reference/object. You are trying to use `Copy` on a `Columns` reference. Try this instead:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastColumn As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TOT")
    lastColumn = ws.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ws.Columns(lastColumn - 2).Insert
    ws.Columns(lastColumn - 2).Insert
    ws.Columns(lastColumn - 2).Insert
    ws.Cells(RowIndex:=1, ColumnIndex:=lastColumn + 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=3).EntireColumn.Copy
    ws.Cells(RowIndex:=1, ColumnIndex:=lastColumn -2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

You need to be careful with this kind of code because the value of lastColumn does not change when you insert the columns so it can become misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub insertNew3Col()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LK As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TOT")
lc = ws.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


ws.Range(Columns(lc - 2), Columns(lc)).Copy
ws.Columns(lc + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```